# Can you query multiple servers on vscode-mssql extension?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have to regularly query one of databases, which are scattered on 6 different servers. I understand the workflow of creating an SQL file and assigning a profile with a single server to it and then using `USE {database_name}` to query a single database.

I don't always remember which server to query, so I either have to guess or check documentation. Can I query all the servers and have IntelliSense autocomplete the name of database like it does with a single server?

I tried to connect to multiple profiles at the same time, but from my understanding it disconnects the previous one.

Comment: you could setup some linked servers, which would allow you to query them from a single server

Comment: @siggemannen is this something I can setup just for myself without admin access to servers or would it need to be added officially by DB admin?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you can access the actual servers in question, i don't think there should be a problem to add them as linked servers, even if an admin have to do it. It doesn't really expose any extra insecurity. You can always try to add one from management studio and see what happens

Comment: You can se [Central Management Server and Server Groups in SSMS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously.md) to query multiple servers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most SQL interfaces like SQL Server Management Studio or MySQL Workbench don't support simultaneous connections to multiple servers for the purpose of IntelliSense or auto-completion. Typically, when you connect to a new server, the previous connection is disconnected, as you've observed.